# set attribute value in a dynamic stylesheet using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to create a dynamic stylesheet using jquery, css, php and html. 
I'm doing an ajax request (with jquery) to give the php css file the width of my screen. 
But my php css file doesn't include the value (window width) in the div (container) for the attribute width that was given by the ajax request.
The Code should work for IE and FF.

*Code:*

**jQuery Ajax**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: true,
    url: 'http://mywebpage/css/template.php',
    data: "bwidth=" + $(window).width(),
    async: false
    }); 
});
```

**Including the php css file**

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/template.php' />
```

**in the php css file**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

$bwidth = isset($_POST['bwidth']) ? (int) $_POST['bwidth'] : 800;
?>

#container
{
width: <?php echo $bwidth . 'px'; ?>; 
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Greets

Comment: It's not acceptable to generate `css` by PHP. Not clean...

Comment: If you only want to manipulate CSS, there is no need for AJAX and PHP.  Just use plain javascript or jquery

Comment: @rid: Ah, is the intent to provide some default values while the CSS is calculated, then replace these default values with the new ones? Yes

Comment: I strongly discourage you to do this though. There are a few issues with this approach: first is the synchronous call. The whole time the server takes to respond, the browser will freeze. Very bad user experience. Then there's the flash of unstyled content. The whole time the server takes to respond, then non-parametrized style will be shown, and then suddenly everything will change. You should consider looking into [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), or even changing CSS attributes via JavaScript directly.

Comment: If you really have to use this approach: Have you already tracked the data being sent to the server by the ajax call (either using the google chrome / firefox developer toolbars or just a plain dump of $_POST in php)?

Answer (score 0):

The new CSS is not applied because you're not doing anything with the AJAX response. [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) returns an object with a `done()` function that you can use to obtain the response text:

```
$.ajax({...}).done(function(css) {
    $('body').append('<style>' + css + '</style>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do it that way (as the comments suggest). CSS and jQuery should look after everything you need to do.

Maybe you need to do some googling on CSS media queries, as it sounds like you want to influence the css based on the screen width.